# After merging, how to interpolate only non-null intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, pandas-merge

I have two sample dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[1100, 1110, 1120, 1130, 1140], 'GR':[40, 50, 60, np.nan, 70]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[1100, 1112, 1118, 1128, 1138], 'VSH':[60, 70, np.nan, 40, 70]})
```

```
   Depth    GR
0   1100  40.0
1   1110  50.0
2   1120  60.0
3   1130   NaN
4   1140  70.0
```

```
   Depth   VSH
0   1100  60.0
1   1112  70.0
2   1118   NaN
3   1128  40.0
4   1138  70.0
```

The first data shows that 'GR' value is null from Depth **1120** till **1140**. Likewise, in the second dataframe 'VSH' is null from Depth from **1112** till **1128**. I want to join these datasets by outer join on 'Depth' and fill null values by interpolation where actually 'GR' is known. What I mean is that in the final joined dataset 'GR' values should not be interpolated (kept null) where Depth of 'GR' is between 1120 and 1140 because at this interval 'GR' is unknown as in the first dataset. Likewise, 'VSH' values between Depth of 1112 and 1128 should be null (not interpolated). The output after interpolation in specific intervals should be like:

```
merged_df = pd.DataFrame({'Depth':[1100, 1110, 1112, 1118, 1120, 1128, 1130, 1138, 1140], 'GR':[40, 50, 53.3, 56.6, 60, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 70], 'VSH':[60, 65, 70, np.nan, np.nan, 40, 55, 70, np.nan]})
```

```
   Depth    GR   VSH
0   1100  40.0  60.0
1   1110  50.0  65.0
2   1112  53.3  70.0
3   1118  56.6   NaN
4   1120  60.0   NaN
5   1128   NaN  40.0
6   1130   NaN  55.0
7   1138   NaN  70.0
8   1140  70.0  NaN
```

**Note:** I just approximately interpolated numbers for GR and VSH where they don't have corresponding Depth in df2 and df1 respectively.

How could you do it in pandas?

Comment: I don't understand the output from 5 to 8 for VSH? Why 40, 50, 60, 70? Where is 80 for VSH at Depth 1138?

Comment: It'd help to include what you have so far. Looks like `df1.merge(df2, on='Depth', how='outer', sort=True)`, yeah? But VSH at 1138 is 80, not 60, so you might need to check the details.

Comment: It's not possible for Depth 1140 to have 85 for VSH. Because now it's an extrapolation not an interpolation.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes. I corrected data, sorry

Comment: @Corralien ahh my bad, yes you are correct

Comment: Sorry for my questions. Can you explain me why for 1110 VSH=65 and not 68.33?

Comment: I just approximately interpolated numbers for VSH where it does not have corresponding Depth in df2. I did not mentioned this in question. It is my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another proposition with a real Depth interpolation:

```
import scipy as sp

# Create interpolation function
gr = sp.interpolate.interp1d(df1['Depth'], df1['GR'], kind='linear', bounds_error=False)
vsh = sp.interpolate.interp1d(df2['Depth'], df2['VSH'], kind='linear', bounds_error=False)

# Compute interpolation for other depths
df1a = pd.DataFrame({'Depth': df2['Depth'], 'GR': gr(df2['Depth'])})
df2a = pd.DataFrame({'Depth': df1['Depth'], 'VSH': vsh(df1['Depth'])})

# Final dataframe
out = (pd.merge(pd.concat([df1, df1a]),
                pd.concat([df2, df2a]))
         .drop_duplicates('Depth')
         .sort_values('Depth', ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   Depth    GR        VSH
0   1100  40.0  60.000000
1   1110  50.0  68.333333
2   1112  52.0  70.000000
3   1118  58.0        NaN
4   1120  60.0        NaN
5   1128   NaN  40.000000
6   1130   NaN  46.000000
7   1138   NaN  70.000000
8   1140  70.0        NaN
```

For GR-1112 and GR-1118, you expect 53.3 and 56.6 because there are two empty values between GR-1110 (50) and GR-1120 (60) but this doesn't take into account the actual value of depth. It makes more sense to me to interpolate based on Depth than the number of missing values, right?

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is also correct.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you don't have infinite values, one option could be to use Inf as sentinel to mark those values not to be interpolated:

```
out = (df1.fillna(np.inf)
          .merge(df2.fillna(np.inf),
                 on='Depth',
                 how='outer',
                 sort=True)
          .interpolate()
          .replace(np.inf, np.nan)
       )
```

Output:

```
   Depth         GR   VSH
0   1100  40.000000  60.0
1   1110  50.000000  65.0
2   1112  53.333333  70.0
3   1118  56.666667   NaN
4   1120  60.000000   NaN
5   1128        NaN  40.0
6   1130        NaN  55.0
7   1138        NaN  70.0
8   1140  70.000000  70.0
```

If you want to interpolate based on Depth and avoid extrapolating:

```
out = (df1.fillna(np.inf)
          .merge(df2.fillna(np.inf),
                 on='Depth',
                 how='outer',
                 sort=True)
          .set_index('Depth')
          .interpolate('index', limit_area='inside')
          .replace(np.inf, np.nan)
          .reset_index()
       )
```

Output:

```
   Depth    GR        VSH
0   1100  40.0  60.000000
1   1110  50.0  68.333333
2   1112  52.0  70.000000
3   1118  58.0        NaN
4   1120  60.0        NaN
5   1128   NaN  40.000000
6   1130   NaN  46.000000
7   1138   NaN  70.000000
8   1140  70.0        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Just want to mention that I should add `limit_area = inside'` parameter in `.interpolate()` function.

Comment: @Muhammad yes, if you don't want to "extrapolate" (rather fill) the external NaNs ;)